# LINQPad4 dump without showing number of results

Tags: linqpad

How do I get .Dump() to work without showing the number of results as the first row?

I've switched a manual report to run via lprun and email to a client. However, I was removing that row manually when I saved the excel file before.

I need to keep the html formatting, so I don't want to do csv. I also use .Dump() in the report (one call at the end), I'm not writing with the html, csv, or xml writers manually.

Comment: _writing with the html, csv, or xml writers manually._ This would have been your answer, but since you don't want to do it manually the answer to your question becomes "You can't"

Comment: Thanks Anthony. Is it bad that I'm thinking about reading in and then ripping out the first header from the html file rather than rewriting the program that makes the report?

Comment: If you update your version of LinqPad in the future, depending on how you're manipulating the raw HTML, your code may break. If you're ripping out the HTML via a proper HTML parser/writer you will probably be safe, otherwise you may consider the likelihood of that happening and manage the risk some other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source of the html generated, the header that contains the number of items is located in `td.typeheader`. I guess you can inject a simple css style into the html generated to hide it :

```
td.typeheader { display: none; }
```

The injection can be a simple replace :

```
File.WriteAllText(pathToReport, File.ReadAllText(pathToReport)
    .Replace("</head>", "<style type=\"text/css\">td.typeheader { display: none; }</script></head>"));
```

Comment: That's a pretty good idea. It may stop working (as mentioned by Anthony), but it wouldn't break the report if it did.

Comment: Good call. Very unlikely to stop working: any changes I might make would be inside the style itself, not to its name or existence.